# How to avoid Infinite $digest Loop error while working with ngResource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I am $watching the $scope.randomObjects in my directive. The $watch will throw an error if the function is not stable and I think that my curried function inside getDesiredAmountOfObjects is idempotent. Is here something going on with ngResource -objects that I can not see? 
How can I fix this? Also the desiredAmount is fixed for now.

Here is snippet from my controller:

```
..
        var getDesiredAmountOfObjects = function (objects, randomObjects) {
            return function (desiredAmount) {
                var amount = desiredAmount || 1;

                if (amount >= objects.length) {
                    return objects;
                }

                var randoms = randomObjects.slice(0, amount);

                //logged objects are always the same in each $digest loop.
                //including the $$hashKey
                console.log(random); 

                return randoms;
            };
        };

        //this will initialized only once in controller
        ObjectRes.query(function(data) { 
            $scope.objects = data;
            var randomObjects = [];
            angular.extend(randomObjects, data);
            randomObjects.sort(function () {
                return 0.5 - Math.random();
            });


            $scope.randomObjects = getDesiredAmountOfObjects($scope.objects, randomObjects);
        });

..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see everything because I haven't seen how the `$watch` and views are set up, but something jumps out at me.

If `randomObjects` is being called from within a watcher, and set to a value on the scope which is also watched, it will cause an infinite `$digest` cycle.

This is because you are constantly returning a new array reference (`slice` returns a new array).  The watcher of the result will recognize that the reference changed, which will require a new loop of the digest, which will ask for new `randomObjects` which will trigger that something changed, etc.

Usually, you fix this by making sure your function returns references to the same object, and does not create new arrays.  In your case, you are calling `slice` which creates a new array every time.  You need to make sure this function returns the same array every time.

Something like this, perhaps?

```
    var getDesiredAmountOfObjects = function (objects, randomObjects) {
        var result = [];

        return function (desiredAmount) {
            var amount = desiredAmount || 1;

            if (amount >= objects.length) {
                return objects;
            }

            // clear the result array and put randoms into it
            result.length = 0;
            result.push.apply(result, randomObjects.slice(0, amount));

            //logged objects are always the same in each $digest loop.
            //including the $$hashKey
            console.log(result); 

            return result;
        };
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and knowledge! This worked nicely!

I thinked this way too much and didn't see the obvious.

TIL angular is watching actual objects and not only the $$hashKey.

Comment: Yeah, I get caught up in this problem all the time.  I write my code so functionally, and I don't consider the referential integrity necessary to maintain Angular's watch system.